# How to re-translate image from other website (hiding source URL)

Tags: node.js, image, express, url

I have a link to the image like
[this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDgN5Zb1jR3e_QSGxY34H_rerXa8CbxaPV5v2ep=k-s48) or [that](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b76d281755014be4d32a974bccdd0760?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG).

I'm trying to re-translate this image from other source URL to some link, f.e `http(s)://examplewebsite.com/john`.
So, it doesn't need to be a redirect, but rather "showing" image on a different link. I've tried using `express.static` but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have your express server and you want to include foreign images in response while hiding source url

In the simplest form, every time someone requests your page, you would fetch the image you want, encode it in `base64` and include this base64 as `src` for the img

```
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fetch('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fdb4d2674d818861be4a4139469ebe59?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1')
    .then(res => res.buffer())
    .then(buffer => {
      res.send(`
      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
         <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>hello</p>
        <img src="data:image\png;base64, ${buffer.toString('base64')}" alt="image">
      </body>
      </html>
  `)
    })

})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

ideally you would create a separate endpoint for these images and also cache them (in memory or on hard drive) to not re-download them every time you need them